# How to change JFrame label from JPanel swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Hi i need to change JLabel which is on JFrame, from JPanel. I can change this only when the mouse is moving, but i need to change everytime when score++;

```
private void panelKwadraty1MouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)                                          
{                                              
 jLabel1.setText("Twoj wynik to: "+panelKwadraty1.getScore());
}
```

I need to change when:

```
 if (kwadrat[i].sprawdzKolizje(belka) == 1)
              {
                  kwadrat[i]=new Kwadrat(kwadrat[i].getKolor());
                  score++;
                 // Jframe.jLabel1.setText("Your score is :" + score); <--- i need do that
              }
```

edit:

I solved problem. I used [propertyChangeListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html).

In JFrame:

```
    panelKwadraty1.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            panelKwadraty1PropertyChange(evt);
        }
    });

    private void panelKwadraty1PropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt)
    {
        if(evt.getPropertyName().equals(PanelKwadraty.ZMIANA_WYNIKU)){
            setLabelText(""+evt.getNewValue());
        }
    }
```

In JPanel:

```
  int old_score = score;
  score++;
  this.firePropertyChange(ZMIANA_WYNIKU, old_score, score);
```

Comment: it's jLabel1 a public field in jFrame ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you have provided I assumed that the jLabel1 is public since you are calling it within a method of the panel.

Thus I think that your problem here might be that there are to many changes when you move the mouse and the label is not being repainted quickly enough. To make sure its repaint happens ASAP use code below:

```
    private void setLabelText(String text)
    {
        jLabel1.setText(text);
        jLabel1.paintImmediately(jLabel1.getVisibleRect());
    }
```

Hope that was it.

Comment: @mientus I have some code which I will edit into my current answer which will show you have simply you can get your label. Currently I expired my max edits for the day.

Comment: dobra misiek napisze Ci maila o co mi chodzi ;d

Answer (score 1):

Make `jLabel1` public in JFrame so that JPanel can access it. And if both JFrame and JPanel belongs to same class then just make `jLabel1` global and it will be accessible by jPanel.

Comment: Ok but how to get access to it ? I dont have JFrame variable !

Comment: @mientus: Are both[jFrame, jPanel] in same class?

Comment: @mientus: seems like both are in different classes. in this case make `jLabel1` publicly available by declaring it public or making getter method for it. Then in class where jPanel is you have to create an instance of Class which has jFrame and then do your work.

Comment: jFrame and jPanel aren't these same class.

Comment: @meintus: then look at comment I have posted before you.

Comment: Ok, when i make jlabel public i can't change it because i don't have variable JFrame to change label.

Answer (score 0):

is the control enters the if() ?? you dont have to reference it as JFrame.JLabel if they are in the same window .. You just have to make the JLabel public and call the method 
`jLabel1.setText()` simple.. can you tell us more about where the components are placed ?